# Tag stats missing for tags with no info

Tags: bug, tags

Tag pages usually have a stats section so that you can see when the tag was created, and some more information. Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/snort/info):

[image: Tag info page with stats section]

However, if there is no tag info then the stats section is missing, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ids/info):

[image: Tag info page missing the stats section]

The stats should still show even if there is no usage guidance or tag wiki.

Comment: That's by design. You can't have stats for something that has never been created.

Comment: How about the statistic for when the tag was created?

Comment: Yeah, that's something which I've wanted since ages too. But it probably is a different feature request.

Comment: Why I saw it: I was looking at an off-topic bountied question and wondering if its tags had been created specifically for that question and would thus be roombaed up if the question ever got closed and deleted.

Comment: Btw, not sure if you know, but the date in the first image is not when the tag was created. It was when the tag wiki was created. The username there is the person who created the tag. It is a bit inconsistent.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if something like that was happening. So, another bug?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a bug for that out there somewhere, I learned it from that post a while back. Don't have time to lookup at the moment. (it's getting a bit late here and I need to catch up on sleep) Anyway, the original bug report here is by-design. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That information is for the tag wiki—it doesn't contain any stats for the tag itself.

If there's no tag wiki, there are no stats to view, because no one has created, viewed, or edited it, and it was never active.

---

Minor postscript: One *could* argue that it could count attempts to view the non-existent tag wiki, but that would be another feature request.